# Force a window to be displayed on every workspace

Tags: unity, vlc, workspaces

I like to have VLC media player running in the top corner of the screen while I am working. I have already configured it to always be 'on top'. Now I am trying to figure out how to have it automatically be displayed on all workspaces.

Currently, I right click the the top of the window and select "Always on visible workspace", but I want to skip this step and have it always be on each from the moment it's opened.

Is this even possible? If so how do I configure it?